# Is example response of POST notebooks on OneNote API reference correct?

Tags: onenote

I tried POST notebooks REST API, but the response JSON I got was different from
example response published on POST notebooks API reference.

The reference URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn790583%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Example response JSON on API reference is as follows.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#notebooks",
  "value":[
    {
      "isDefault": false,
      "userRole":"Contributor",
      // Other notebook properties follow.
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the response JSON I got was follows.

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#notebooks",
  "isDefault": false,
  "userRole":"Contributor",
  // Other notebook properties follow.
}
```

The actual response JSON had not "value" and the actual JSON object of notebook properties
was not element of "value" array.

Is the reference correct?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a problem in our reference documentation. We will get it updated ASAP!

Thanks.